# Angular2 Http / Jsonp Not Making Request

Tags: rest, angular, angular2-services

I'm using Angular `2.0.0-beta.16` and attempting to get data from my RESTful API. I have the following service:

```
import {Injectable}     from 'angular2/core';
import {Jsonp, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from 'angular2/http';
import {Store}          from './store';
import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class StoreService {
    constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp) {

    }

    getStores(): Observable<Store[]> {
      console.log("getting stores");
      // let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      // let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.jsonp.get("http://localhost:8080/stores")
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
      console.log(res.status);
        if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
            throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
        }
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || {};
    }


    private handleError(error: any) {
        // In a real world app, we might send the error to remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg = error.message || 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

From my component, I'm calling `getStores()`. I know it is getting into the `getStores()` function because I am getting the `console.log` message. However, nothing else happens. No request is being made that I can see in the chrome dev tools. No errors being logged to the console. Just nothing. I've tried both `Jsonp` and `Http` but they both give the same results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the observable returned by `getStores()`. Observables are lazy and don't do anything without `subscribe()` or `toPromise()

```
getStores().subscribe(val => { console.log(val); };
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks. Would you mind linking to some docs on this particular nugget?

Comment: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html Your link seems broken.